# Two Dimensional aligning with flexbox (CSS noob headache)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After I defined my side menu, I came over this wall that I find hard to break. Thinking back, I should have use css grid instead.

I couldn't find a way to position my `main` element to the right side of the `nav` element. I just want to see that `H3` in the middle of the remaining `body` space, to the right. I'm struggling for 2 hours by now so I came to ask for some help.

You have to open fullscreen to really see the page, I haven't created any media queries yet so the style gets stretchy.

Hope you guys have a few minutes to spend with a CSS noob :).

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:00,500,600,700|Open+Sans:400,400i,600);
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/et-line@1.0.1/style.css);

/* Global Tweaks */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0
}

body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
}

.main-menu, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

a:focus, a:hover, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0
}
/* Global Tweaks */

/* Side Menu*/
a:active {
    background-color: #333;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 25%;
}

nav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 30vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;  
}  

nav ul li a:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}

nav ul li:first-child a::before {
    display: none
}

.main-menu {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

.main-menu li {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }

nav ul li a i {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    color: #838383;
    font-size: 2em;
}

a[href^="#"] {
    font-size: 1.05em;
    color: #212121;

}
/* Side Menu*/

/* Content Wrapper */

.author h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #222;
}

/* Content Wrapper */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portofoliu</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main-mobile.css" media="print"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    
    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    
    <!-- Responsive -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Side Menu -->
    <nav>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="home active"><a class="logo" href="#home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#cine-sunt"><i class="icon-profile-male"></i>Cine sunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#proiecte"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i>Proiecte</a></li>
            <li><a href="#servicii"><i class="icon-adjustments"></i>Servicii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact"><i class="icon-envelope"></i>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- Side Menu -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <main class="home-card">
        <section class="author">
            <h3>My Name</h3>
        </section>
    </main>
    <!-- Content -->
</body>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the nav and main tags to a wrapper like `.nav_wrapper` then use flex display to the wrapper as follows to show them side-by-side.

```
.nav_wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

More information about the flex style can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).